# How to compare filename with a string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, compare, pickle

I'm making a program in which you can store your data and it will have a unique code from which you can load that back. So I've made way to make a unique code by just putting the date and then putting the entry number. For example: The date is 24 April 2021 and it is the first entry of the day then it'll generate the code as 202104241. The "1" at the end means entry number 1. So i want that to change every time you make a new entry in that day. I tried it doing like this but it gives an error. Is there any to do it?

```
def New_Document():
  LUD = 1 # LAST UNIQUE DIGIT
  unique = []
  date = datetime.date.today()
  unique.append(date)
  unique_id = str(unique[0])
  unique_id = unique_id.replace('-', '')
  unique_id = unique_id + str(LUD)

  folder = r'E:\\Programming related\\DATASAVER'
  destination = r'E:\\Programming related\\DATASAVER\\DATA'
  filenames = os.listdir(destination)

  print(filenames)
  
  

  for file in filenames:
    if filenames[file] in unique_id:
        LUD += 1
        unique_id = unique_id + str(LUD)
        break
    else:
        continue
  
  
        

  print(f"Your  unique id is: {unique_id}")
  pickle.dump(unique_id, open(unique_id, 'wb'))
  shutil.move(folder, destination)



print("Please choose a NUMBER:")
print("1: New Document")
print("2: Existing Document")
while True:
    try:
        ask = int(input("Please enter a NUMBER: "))
        if ask == 1:
          break
        elif ask == 2:
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter '1' OR '2'")
            continue
    except:
        print("Please '1' OR '2' NOT a WORD")

if ask == 1:
    New_Document()
else:
    pass
```

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Your posted code is 50 lines for a 3-line problem -- all of that data input and processing is irrelevant to the simple issue of how to convert dates from one format to another.

Comment: See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).  Look for the `datetime` package; make an attempt with the tools that were designed to handle this class of problem.

Comment: What is your problem here?